# Is there a replace function in liquibase?

Tags: java, liquibase

Liquibase offers the update function which updates the whole value in the column. Is there also a way to just replace a part of the value? Or do I have to use plain sql statements for it?

The value in the column looks like this:

```
downtime = maintenanceTime + rampUpTime + repairTime;
```

when calling

```xml
<changeSet author="faf" id="29.10.19-16:34-001">
    <update tableName="PARAMETER">
        <column name="VALUE" type="varchar(64)" value="setupTime" />
        <where>VALUE LIKE '%rampUpTime%'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

it translates it to

```sql
UPDATE parameter set VALUE = 'setupTime'  where VALUE like '%rampUpTime%'
```

I'm searching for something similar which will be translated into

```sql
UPDATE parameter
SET VALUE = REPLACE(VALUE, 'rampUpTime', 'setupTime')
WHERE VALUE LIKE '%rampUpTime%';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Liquibase doesn't offer `REPLACE`, but it offers `valueComputed` attribute for an `<update>` tag.

I think the following should do the trick:

```
<changeSet author="faf" id="29.10.19-16:34-001">
    <update tableName="PARAMETER">
        <column name="VALUE" type="varchar(64)" valueComputed="REPLACE(VALUE, 'rampUpTime', 'setupTime')" />
        <where>VALUE LIKE '%rampUpTime%'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Can you explain what the ˋvalueComputedˋ is doing? Just saw that it is available for many tags.

Comment: It computes the results of SQL query you provide as value of ‘valueComputed’ and interprets it as static value of whatever it is used for.